# Intuitive explanation of the maximas of the function $\sin(\pi x)/x^2$

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry, maxima-minima

I came across this function while playing around in desmos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jp0kirirgk
[image]

What I cannot understand is :

1. Why are the maximas of $\sin(\pi x)/x^2$ shifted from the maximas of $\sin(\pi x)$?
2. Why do these maximas approach those of $\sin(\pi x)$ as $x$ tends to infinity?

I can understand it analytically by computing the derivative of the function which comes out to be

$$
f'(x)= \frac{\pi x^2\cos(\pi x)-2x\sin(\pi x)}{x^4}=\frac{2\cos(\pi x)(\pi x/2 - \tan(\pi x))}{x^3}
$$

and then using the [first derivative test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test)
so the maximas only exist where $\tan(\pi x)=\pi x/2$;
but I am looking for a moral justification.

Comment: A rough explanation for 1 could be: for $x_0$ a maximum of $\sin(\pi x)$ and $x<x_0$ close to $x_0,$ $\sin(\pi x)$ will be a little smaller than $\sin(\pi x_0)$ but this will be compensated by the fact that $\frac1{x^2}$ is a little bigger that $\frac1{x_0^2}.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Good observation, so as x tends to infinity $1/x^2$ tends to zero which also explains (2)

Comment: I am not pleased with it, and find it unsufficient to explain 2. May be you can do better, and [post a self-answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is best understood as a product of two functions, one being $f_1(x)=\sin(\pi x)$, the other being $f_2(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$.

The answer to your two questions is:

1. The maximas shift because if $x_0$ is the maximum of $f_1$, then going a bit to the left, to $x_0-\epsilon$, will cause $f_1$ to decrease very slightly, while $f_2$ will increase *more* (because the absolute value of its derivative is bigger), so their product will increase. The more to the left you move, however, the stronger $f_1$'s decrease becomes, until it eventually overpowers $f_2$'s increase.
2. As $x$ becomes bigger, the absolute value of $f_2$'s derivative **decreases**, so the effect described above becomes smaller. $f_2$ increases *less* as you move left of $f_1$'s maximum, and therefore its increase can more easily be overpowered by $f_1$'s decrease (which remains the same).

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=\frac{\sin (\pi  x)}{x^2}\quad \implies \quad f'(x)=\frac{\pi  x \cos (\pi  x)-2 \sin (\pi  x)}{x^3}$$
Because if the $x$ term in front of the derivative, the extrema take place closer and closer to $m=n+\frac 12$.

Using series expansion around this point and continuing with series reversion
$$x_f=m-\frac{2}{\pi ^2 m}-\frac{4}{3 \pi ^4 m^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{m^5}\right)$$ whiel for $g(x)=\sin(\pi x)$ the extrema are at
$x_g=m$. So, more or less, the shift is given by
$$x_g-x_f \sim \frac{2}{\pi ^2 m}$$ which tends to zero when $m$ increases.